# SQL Optimizing with multiple JOIN and OR Operator

Tags: sql, optimization

I have a query where I am looking for the best method of query optimization. This is the query that I have produced. Is there a better method to optimize this to reduce memory, CPU usage and make it faster?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,country,c.id 
id_employer,c.comp_name,c.show_comp_name,comp_type,b.id countryid,if(now()
<a.hotjob_expire, true, false) is_hot 
FROM j5xap_jbjobs_job a 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_country b ON a.id_country = b.id 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_employer c ON a.employer_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_custom_field_value cv ON cv.jobid=a.id 
LEFT JOIN j5xap_jbjobs_comp_type d ON c.id_comp_type = d.id 
WHERE (
          a.job_title LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR a.state LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR a.city LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR b.country LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR c.comp_name LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR cv.value LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR cv.valuetext LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR a.short_desc LIKE '%Web developer%' 
       OR a.long_desc LIKE '%Web developer%'
      ) 
   OR (
          a.job_title LIKE '%kannur%' 
       OR a.state LIKE '%kannur%'
       OR a.city LIKE '%kannur%' 
       OR b.country LIKE '%kannur%' 
       OR c.comp_name LIKE '%kannur%' 
       OR cv.value LIKE '%kannur%' 
       OR cv.valuetext LIKE '%kannur%' 
       OR a.short_desc LIKE '%kannur%' 
       OR a.long_desc LIKE '%kannur%'
    ) 
    AND a.id_job_spec =441 
    AND a.id_job_spec IN (SELECT id FROM j5xap_jbjobs_job_spec WHERE id_category='63') 
    AND a.is_active='y' 
    AND a.publish_date <= '2017-07-07 00:00:00' 
    AND expire_date  >= '2017-07-07 00:00:00' 
    AND expire_date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
 ORDER BY is_hot DESC, a.is_featured DESC, a.publish_date DESC, a.id DESC
 LIMIT 0, 10;
```

My original thought was that multiple joins should be split into single select statements, however with these multiple OR operators. It makes it a little tricky.

Would appreciate any assistance.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are missing a set of parens??? `WHERE ((` ... `OR a.long_desc like '%Kannur%'))`

Comment: I've reformatted to make more readable, but I still think you are missing a set of parens.

Comment: Also you are specifying two conditions for `a.id_job_spec` I don't think you probably intended to do that.

Comment: In short, I think this query is probably not returning the data you want so you should probably fix it before trying to optimise it.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is MySQL?  Changing tags.

Answer (score 0):

`OR` is inefficient.

`LIKE '%...'` is inefficient.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` *may* be inefficient.  Change to `EXISTS(...)` or `JOIN`.

Proper use of a MySQL `FULLTEXT` index (and modifying the query to use it) will speed up the query a lot.

What table is `expire_date` in?

This composite index *might* help:

```
INDEX(id_job_spec, is_active, publish_date)
```